# Vim upside down question marks on whitespace

Tags: vim, encoding, ssh, vagrant

I've installed [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) on my Vagrant machine with Ubuntu.

The issue is that when I log into Vagrant with `vagrant ssh` and run Vim then I get all these upside down question marks on either making a space or a tab.

In ~/.vimrc I've got:

`scriptencoding utf-8

set encoding = utf-8

set termencoding = utf-8`

Comment: There must be no spaces around the `=` assignment in `:set`, but I doubt that's your problem, since it would cause visible errors.

Comment: Why would you use `set encoding = utf-8`? It's seems safer to just set it in your LOCALE, so you still can edit non-ascii/UTF files like ISO8859-1 without breaking them.

Comment: timss: You may be misunderstanding what the `'encoding'` option is for.  You can set it to "UTF-8" safely without risking damaging files, as Vim has a `'fileencoding`' option as well.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try `:set nolist` which tells vim not visually list space-like characters.
You can check `:h 'list'`, `:h 'listchars'` for further reference.